# Shrink container to fit only visible items

Tags: html, css

Is there a pure CSS-based solution to shrink a container (in this case UL) to fit only visible (and not overflow) items?

The output on the right is what I want (achieved by setting `display:none` to the overflown item):

```css
.container {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px; 
  width: 240px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
.foo {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: green;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="foo">Foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li style="display:none;"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="foo">Foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLgQKq?editors=1100#0)

Comment: white-space + display maybe ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZOdqBp?editors=1100#0

Comment: You need to identify what constitutes overflow content. After a certain number of `li` elements, or a specific width, etc? Edit: never mind I didn't see you had a `width` set on your container element. Yeah `white-space: nowrap` would do it. Do you want them to just not be seen at all or should the container scroll over so you can view them?

Comment: Visibility is not an issue. I want UL to shrink to only visible items (and not the overflown ones). So as you can see on the right in the codepen, UL occupies width of only 3 list items. I want to achieve the same without setting display:none to overflown items.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.container`.

```css
.container {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  width: 240px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  overflow: hidden; /* NEW */
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
.foo {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: green;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="foo">Foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, while it causes the overflown list item to hide, it doesn't shrink the UL container to visible items only.

Comment: @dytrivedi, remove `display: table-cell`